# How To accept XML Payload request in webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Can any one please explain how to accept the xml data payload thrrough webapi post request because when we send the payload request i need to validate the data, so can anyone please explain how to accept the xml data through post in webapi and c#

Thanks in Advance,
Hemanth